# Add additional arguments to shiny functions

Tags: html, r, shiny

Is it possible to add additinal html arguments to shiny functions?

For example, shiny extInput function has the form:

```
textInput(inputId, label, value = "", width = NULL, placeholder = NULL)
```

I would like to constraint maximum number of characters the user can type in. In html, I can do that using `maxlength` attribute:

```
"<form action='demo_form.asp'>
                   <b>Input</b> 
                   <br>
                   <input type='text' name='oib' maxlength='11'size='30'><br>
                   <br>
                   <input type='submit' value='Search'>
                   </form>"
```

Do I have to use raw HTML code to add this attribute to shiny or I can somehow add to shiny function?

Can I see the original html code for shiny text input function?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27181420/how-to-limit-the-number-of-characters-accepted-by-textinput-in-shiny-app